# How to 'conda env create -f environment.yml' using 'pip --user' method

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, azure-web-app-service

I am running into a permissions error when trying to create a conda environment from environment.yml.

Code:

```
conda env update -f environment.yml
```

Result:

```
Pip subprocess error:
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\VSSADM~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-uninstall-y6pkbh0y\\_cffi_backend.cp36-win_amd64.pyd'

Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

Is it possible to run a conda installation while using the --user flag for pip? I don't see anything in the documentation. This is happening on an azure app-service instance so I don't think that running as administrator is an option.

As requested, here is the yml used in azure pipelines:

```
- task: CondaEnvironment@0
  inputs:
    environmentName: 'REDACTED' 
    packageSpecs: 'python=3.6.10'
  displayName: 'Install Conda'

- script: |
    conda env update -p C:\Miniconda\envs -f environment.yml
  displayName: 'Sync Conda Environment'
```

UPDATE: Azure app service does not allow you to run conda using administrator previledges. To anyone tempted to try and run azure app service with conda: Don't bother. It's not supported and it's not worth the headache trying to get around it. I have everything working just fine on a azure windows server VM running a wfastcgi API with IIS 6.

Answer (score 3):

You have to run cmd as admin and type the same command again.
If you don't have admin permissions as you say you should add this to your command `-p` as follows.

```
conda env update -p C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs -f environment.yml
```

Comment: Got:   unrecognized arguments: --user

Comment: you have to place the -p flag and add the PATH to YOUR env i added an example PATH.

Comment: The use-local flag also caused a syntax error for me. I'm trying your path method now

Comment: Yeah sorry about the use-local it does not work, the path should work though

Comment: So, did it work in the end, or are you still having issues?

Comment: The build just failed with the same error  as listed in the question. Adding a path didn't seem to influence permissions

Comment: could you post the path you used pls

Comment: also could i see the .yml file i have a feeling that it's trying to create an env that you need admin permissions to create.

Comment: `conda env update -p C:\Miniconda\envs -f environment.yml`

Comment: your path has to show to your user accont if not you need admin permission for example

Comment: This is in an azure pipeline VM (shared hosting). Unfortunately, there are no user folders.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223661/discussion-between-cforce99-and-daniel-scott).

Comment: When you open cmd what is the path you see? I see C:\Users\myusername